# Report Displaying unmatched data in SSRS?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008

hi i created one report in SSRS by using stored procedure but it is displaying the data even though record is not existing in table.

but coming to procedure if i am executing it in my sql server it is running fine.

can any body tell me how to over come this situation

Answer (score 0):

In a 2008 SSRS report project the designer seems to cache data unless a refresh to the parameters, datasources or dataset is issued. Also, a report UI change should cause the VS2008 reportviewer to refresh. If you do not modify the report it will use a cached version of data for an undetermined amout of time. Could this be what you are seeing?

Comment: Ltn , every time i am using refresh fields in query designer , eventhough it is showing the same report for not existing user id